# Ajuda com EventEmitter - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

não estou conseguindo emitir um evento para outro, alguém conseguiria me ajudar ?

Basicamente o que eu estou tentando fazer é que quando eu salvar algo no component 1 ele emita o evento para o component 2 para que seja atualizado a informação dinamicamente na tela.

**Compartilhei todo o código neste link:
https://pastebin.com/k8VhDfnx**

Caso seja relevante abaixo uma representação da estrutura do meu app.component:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <sge-header></sge-header>
    <sge-aside></sge-aside>

      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 content-custom">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
      </div>
      <sge-footer></sge-footer>
</div>
```

Grato.

Comment: qual o problema da emissão?

Comment: Não está emitindo...o método responsável por capturar o evento dentro da classe area-list nunca é executado